# How to call both javascript function and C# function on a single button click in MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to call a javascript and a function written in Model Class using a single button click. I used the following code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function RunEXE() {
        var txtfile = document.getElementById("txtFileName");
        //var txtProgram = document.getElementById("txtProgram");
        //if ((!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtfile)) && (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtProgram))) {
        if (txtfile.value != "") {
            var oShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
            //var prog = "c:\\Pgms\\sample0.exe";

            var prog = "\\\\Test-PC\\Programms\\" + txtfile.value + ".exe";
            oShell.Run('"' + prog + '"', 1);
        } else {
            alert('The file name must be entered in file name textbox');

        }
    }
    </script>

<input type="submit" name="button" value="Run" onclick="RunEXE()" />
```

The below code is Model function:

```
public ActionResult Run(UserProgram userProgram)
    {
        SaveAndCompile(userProgram);
        return null;
    }
```

But its working with Run() alone and not running RunEXE()

Comment: Your function in JavaScript will probably not be executed because when you click on a submit button, the default behavior is to cancel all pending processing in js. Is your _Run_ method marked with HttpPost?

Answer (score 1):

```
[HttpPost]
```

public ActionResult RunAction(string option1)
{
    //if needed, you can use the "option1" value to determine the UserProgram to pass
    UserProgram userProgram = new UserProgram();
    Run(userProgram);

```
//you can return a JSON reuslt that you can evaluate back at the client
return Json(new { @Success = true, @MyString = "a string" });
```

}

```
$.post('@Url.Action("RunAction", "MyController")',
  {
     option1: "some optional value"
  },
  function (data) {
      alert("success!");
      //here you have access to your JSON result via data, for example:
      //data.Success = true
      //data.MyString = "a string"
  }
```

);

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can submit your form by JQuery submit function.

I assume your code will like below:

```
<form id="form" action="/Run">
// your some inputs
<input type="submit" name="button" value="Run" />
</form>
```

And the javascript for submitting will be:

```
$(function() {
    $('#form').submit(function() {
        // to do something before the form is submitted
        RunEXE();
        return true; // return false to cancel form action
    });
});
```

Cheers.